# Placeholder opens jQuery UI autocomplete combobox on page load (IE10)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, placeholder

I'm using jQuery UI autocomplete combobox widget. When i add placeholders on my comboboxes, the autocomplete boxes are opened by default.

This occurs **only on IE10 and later**.

This is my code :

```
 _create: function () {
            this.wrapper = $("<span>")
            .addClass("custom-combobox")
            .insertAfter(this.element);
            this.element.hide();
            this._createAutocomplete();
            this._createShowAllButton(); 
            this.input.attr("placeholder", this.element.attr('placeholder'));
        },
```

Comment: please write some more details about the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We noticed that the issue was being solved by actually *focusing* the comboboxes.

Once the combobox is focused, the autocomplete box disappeared and it remained that way when the combobox *lost* focus.

So, our solution was a bit *hack-ish*, we added a `.focus()` followed by a `.blur()` :

```
 _create: function () {
            this.wrapper = $("<span>")
            .addClass("custom-combobox")
            .insertAfter(this.element);
            this.element.hide();
            this._createAutocomplete();
            this._createShowAllButton(); 
            this.input.attr("placeholder", this.element.attr('placeholder'));

            this.input.focus().blur();
          //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Voila!
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem in IE10+ but just when we add a placeholder with **special characters** (German "Umlaute").

**The solution by Seckin solved also our problem** - after 1 day of hard Google work ;-)

Tried to vote for the answer- but as a newbie I haven't the reputation for doing so...

```
_create: function () {
        this.wrapper = $("<span>")
        .addClass("custom-combobox")
        .insertAfter(this.element);
        this.element.hide();
        this._createAutocomplete();
        this._createShowAllButton(); 

        this.input.attr( "placeholder", 'Bitte wählen' );
        this.input.focus().blur();

    },
```

Comment: I'm really glad it helped! Thanks for the credit @oekokroete, however since it is the same solution; I don't think this should be an answer, you're welcome to add this as a comment on the existing answer.