# jQuery ui combo-box opens on default in IE 10

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer, combobox

I am using jQuery UI Autocomplete to display combo boxes in my UI. I referred the following url http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox  for rendering comboBoxes.For my drop down having ID say "myComboBox", I have set the combo-box to focus when the page loads using the following.

```
$('#myComboBox').next().find('input').focus();
```

This works fine in chrome and IE 9,however in IE 10 the combo boxes open by default prior to any user selection. Is there any  workaround for this particular bug in IE version 10

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/28143320/2065039 answer you need to try adding a `focus` to your `autocomplete` and then `blur` it something like

```
_create: function () {
         this.input.focus().blur();
},
```

OR

```
$('#myComboBox').next().find('input').focus().blur();
```

Comment: Glad it worked!! :) Mark it as answer so that it will be useful to others too!! :) Happy coding.. :) @AnanthKumble

Comment: Even though this works, it produces another problem - the page somewhat scrolls to the focused element....