# Page Scrolls when focusing on jquery ui-autocomplete-combobox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I just had the same problem  with JQuery autocomplete/ combox as described here:
[Placeholder opens jQuery UI autocomplete combobox on page load (IE10)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28126306/placeholder-opens-jquery-ui-autocomplete-combobox-on-page-load-ie10?noredirect=1&lq=1)
the solution to use

```
this.input.focus().blur();
```

is very smart but like @walther comments here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30026430/1836255
the page scrolls to the focused element. This can be very annoying when you have a large form with the Combobox at the bottom of it as the page scrolls down to the element.

I already tried to scroll up to the top of the page with Jquery on document ready using

```
jQuery('#datenblattconainer').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 2);
```

but then the page first scrolls down and then up again - which also is not such a nice user expierence...

Any help would be much appreciated ;-)